# How to divide natural number N into M nearly equal summands?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, integer-programming

How to divide natural number N into M nearly equal summands?

For example, to divide 20 by 13, in geometric representation, I should get

[image]

How to generate the sequence above?

What is the name of this operation? It is close to division, but exact and giving unequal summands as a result.

P.S. Also this is probably related with leap years / calendar calculations.

**UPDATE**

Regarding examples where we get

$20=2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+1+1+1+1$

I think it is not ballanced in the middle:

[image]

I would like partial sums be close to ratio as much as possible.

Comment: Do you want it always on or below the line (but as close as possible), or do you want it always as close to the line as possible even if that takes it above the line?

Comment: See also: [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: See also [One dimensional error diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_diffusion#One-dimensional_error_diffusion). You make an up-move whenever the accumulated error is more than $1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the sequence
$$\left\lfloor\frac{N k}{M}\right\rfloor, \qquad k = 0,\ldots, M.$$
which for $N = 20, M = 13$, gives
$$0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20.$$
The differences between successive terms are
$$\left\lfloor\frac{N (k + 1)}{M}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{N k}{M}\right\rfloor, \qquad k = 0,\ldots, M - 1.$$
In our example,
$$1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2,$$
and the reverse of this is
$$\phantom{(\ast)\qquad} 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, \qquad(\ast)$$
which is nearly the sequence given.

> I claim that $(\ast)$ is actually the sequence you want, rather than the given one. Notice, for example, that if we take the origin to be the bottom-leftmost corner, the line passes through $\left(3, \frac{39}{20}\right)$, which is below the marked point $(3, 2)$; so, in the diagram, the red step curve actually crosses the black diagonal, which I presume is undesired.

Reversing the order in the sequence of differences exchanges the $k$th term with the $(M - k - 1)st$ (for every $k$), so the general formula for the desired sequence is
$$\color{#df0000}{\left\lfloor\frac{N (M - k)}{M}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{N (M - k - 1)}{M}\right\rfloor, \qquad k = 0,\ldots, M - 1}.$$

**Remark** One can alternately produce more "balanced" partitions by rounding each multiple $\frac{Nk}{M}$ to the nearest integer (rather than flooring):
$$\left\lfloor\frac{N k}{M} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor, \qquad n=0,\ldots, M$$
(this convention rounds $\frac{1}{2}$ up). The resulting sequence of differences is
$$\left\lfloor\frac{N (M - k)}{M} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{N (M - k - 1)}{M} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor, \qquad n=0,\ldots, M - 1,$$
which for our example is the aesthetically pleasing
$$2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2.$$

Comment: Such easy, thanks. I understand I made some obvious mistakes drawing by eye...

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the division algorithm to write $N$ as $aM+r$ with $0\leq r<M$

Then $N$ can be seen as $r$ times the number $a+1$ and $M-r$ times the number $a$.

---

Example: you want to divide $20$ by $13$. We get $20=1\cdot13+7$, here $a=1$ and $r=7$

Then we use the above and get $20$ is the same as $7$ times $1+1=2$ plus $13-7=6$ times $1$.

So we get $20=2+2+2+2+2+2+2+1+1+1+1+1+1$

Answer (score 1):

We note that in general we can express some number $n$ as the sum of $m$ "almost equal" parts, such that:

$$n=\left\lceil\frac{n}{m} \right\rceil+\cdots+\left\lceil \frac{n-m+1}{m} \right\rceil = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left\lceil\frac{n-k}{m}\right\rceil$$

So for each bin $k \in \{1,m\}$ we have the number of items in it:

$$N_{k}=\left\lceil\frac{n-k+1}{m}\right\rceil$$

So for your example where $n=20$, $m=13$ we have the number in each bin:

$$\{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$$

Which corresponds to your example. I hope this helps!

Comment: I think your sequence will not touch the line in the middle? I would like to interchange summands so that they tend to be as close to the ratio, as possible.

Comment: @SuzanCioc What do you mean by "touch the line in the middle"?

Comment: Wait me thinking :)

Comment: I've made very good use of this since finding it in March (it was exactly what I'd been looking for). Thank you Thomas